# what all permission i need to publish on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to publish post on facebook via my website.

I have these permissions

```php
'scope' => 'read_stream, email, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos',
```

But I am unable to publish a post. Example is below which i cant publish.

```php
if(isset($_POST['publish'])){
    try{
        $statusUpdate = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
            'message'       => 'Message here',
            'link'          => 'webiste link here',
            'picture'       => 'image link here',
            'name'          => 'Heading',
            'caption'       => 'example.com',
            'description'   => 'bla bla bla bla',
            ));
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
    }
}
```

But I am successfully able to post simple posts(status) with just message

```php
if(isset($_POST['status'])){
    try{
        $statusUpdate = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array('message'=> $_POST['status']));
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
    }
}
```

Can any one tell me what additional permission I need or what I am missing?

with Graph API I get this error

```php
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

In my `error_log.php` i found this

**OAuthException: (#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.**

Comment: what is the error caught ?

Comment: I added error above in my question when i try it with graph api

Comment: Try to set "Stream Post Url Security" to false in App Setting

Comment: wow it worked out ty you can added your answer i will vote up it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tackle the error: `(#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.`, you have to set "Stream Post Url Security" to **false** in App Setting.

Sidenote: You don't need `user_birthday` and others to publish a feed. Only `publish_stream` is required.